# Refrence to a subsubsection of another chapter as hyperlink

Tags: cross-referencing

I wanted to refer to a subsubsection in the text which is in another chapter, in a hyper-link manner.

Applied code:

```
In **section~\ref{4.1.1.1}** required aspects for defining the minimum and maximum limit for gross error check are provided. Hence, for this research gross errors are those observations that lay outside the minimum of $3^\circ$C and maximum of 25^\circ$C.
```

Where Refereed subsubsection is presented:

```
**4.1.1.1 Data Cleaning: Gross Error Identication**
Plausible value check (Zahumensky and SHMI, 2004) is used to identify gross errors.
```

Comment: Did you put a `\label{4.1.1.1}` on the right place?

Comment: No, I did not put that. The problem is solved.